# how to get file upload percentage(progress) using fetch api in reactjs or nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using `Nextjs` to build a full-stack application I working on the admin cms and I try to upload a file like an image or etc. I do this from this [post](https://codesandbox.io/s/thyb0) with a little difference in UI.
The upload function is good and everything is good with no errors and no problems. But I need to show upload progress or a percentage to the user but every topic I read on every site doesn't help me. how to do this?

front-end code:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import Theme from "../components/layouts/theme";

const Home = (props) => {
  const choosenFile = useRef();
  const [staticImage, setStaticImage] = useState();

  const handleForm = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const myFile = choosenFile.current.files;
    const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(myFile[0]);

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", myFile[0]);

    try {
      const response = await console.log("status", response);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
      }

      const responseData = await response.json();

      console.log("response", responseData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("upload", err);
    }
  };

  const setImage = (param) => {
    setStaticImage(URL.createObjectURL(param));
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {staticImage && (
        <>
          <div
            className="thumbnail"
            style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
          >
            <Image
              src={staticImage}
              width={300}
              height={300}
              layout="responsive"
            />
          </div>
          <p>The upload percentage shows here: <span className="text-danger">10%</span></p>
        </>
      )}
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-10 p-5">
          <form onSubmit={handleForm}>
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
              <input
                type="file"
                name="docs"
                ref={choosenFile}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setImage(e.target.files[0]);
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                Send
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Home.getLayout = function getLayout(Home) {
  return <Theme>{Home}</Theme>;
};

export default Home;
```

The API route code:

```
import formidable from "formidable";
import fs from "fs";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const post = async (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
    await saveFile(files.file);
    return res.status(201).json({ message: "Upload was succesfull!" });
  });
};

const saveFile = async (file) => {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(file.filepath);
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(`./public/uploads/${file.originalFilename}`, data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err', err);
  }

  await fs.unlinkSync(file.filepath);
  return;
};

export default (req, res) => {
  req.method === "POST"
    ? post(req, res)
    : req.method === "PUT"
    ? console.log("PUT")
    : req.method === "DELETE"
    ? console.log("DELETE")
    : req.method === "GET"
    ? console.log("GET")
    : res.status(404).send("");
};
```

[image]

I use the `formidable` package to handle `formData` and `fs` to manage file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can use `axios`. for more information visit [npm.com/package/axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

in `home.js` file handle replace `fetch` request whit this code:

```
axios.post("/api/upload", data, {
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        // console.log('progressEvent', progressEvent)
        if (progressEvent.bytes) {
          console.log(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)*100));
          
        }
      },
    });
```